# Combine Javascripts into one js and defer if possible

Tags: javascript, jquery

These are the last 3 lines I have before the closing body tag. I want to combined them all into 1 js and possibly defer until after the page loads, but I can not get it to work just in one js file within the html.

All 3 are used for a slideshow.

I can combine jquery-1.3.2.min.js and the loopedslider2.js into one, but as soon as I add the function to the js the slideshow does not work at all. I am not understanding why when each are called separate...it works when combined it doesn't.

```
<script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js">

<script src="loopedslider2.js">

<script>$(function(){$('#loopedSlider1').loopedSlider1({autoStart:6000,restart:500,slidespeed:600,autoHeight:true});});</script>



<script>function downloadJSAtOnload(){
var element = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "x.js";document.body.appendChild(element);}
if (window.addEventListener)window.addEventListener
("load",downloadJSAtOnload,false);
else if(window.attachEvent)window.attachEvent("onload",downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload=downloadJSAtOnload;</script>
```

Comment: You need to close your script tags. Use `</script>` even after the external scripts.

Comment: First of all: if this is at the end of the `<body>`, then it *is* deferred.

Second point: all of those scripts would work perfectly fine if you put them in the `<head>`, which is a more appropriate place for them.

Comment: Are you combining them in the right order? If so, you might try sticking a `;` between scripts.

Comment: @nrabinowitz No, the semicolon is optional. It's not causing any problems here.

Comment: @rvighne Why is head a more appropriate place? That's wrong, they should be at the bottom, so that the page gets loaded first. Secondly, semicolons are not always optional, they can cause problems. Read here: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Semicolons#Semicolons

Comment: OT: Which tool are you using to combine (and probably minify) the files and what settings are you using? Some settings (like advanced in Google Closure compiler) can cause scripts to break. You should probably first test with the most conservative settings.

Comment: @Kenneth OK, let's not get off topic, but... `<head>` is the correct place to put it. That's why there's a script `defer` attribute: so people get the same effect but have their scripts in the correct place.

Comment: That only works if you're targetting IE9+, beneath that, it's buggy. So no, the correct place is at the bottom if you support older browsers

Comment: @rvighne Sorry I have closing script tags on all 3, just didn't copy/paste correctly

Comment: any error information? or can we see the source of loopslider2.js? i'm guessing that the contents of loopslider2.js are not wrapped in a closure.

Comment: @rvighne placing js within script tags at the end or head is not deferring for what I want it for.  I have updated my post with defer script.  If I combined all 3 and called it x.js (as an example) the piece I added would defer it until the page loaded. By doing this I am able to increase my page speed. By having it in the head or script tags it counts against your page speed.

Comment: @awei  see here http://jsfiddle.net/tS27H/

Comment: I know and understand the fiddle does not work...using it to show the loopslider2.js

Comment: @rvighne - Semicolons are not always optional in this case; it depends on the content of the files, how they're compressed, etc. For example, if one script has the content `(function() {}(this))` (std module pattern) and the next has `!function() {}(this)` (fancy Bootstrap module pattern) you get a syntax error.

Comment: @KurtMarshman I understand the speed argument. But the `defer` attribute on `<script>`s gives the same effect as if the script was in the body, and some browsers even load the JS on the side.

Comment: @awei I am not seeing any errors.  Just a blank slideshow.

Comment: @KurtMarshman - you know there's an error in the loopslider2.js code you posted, right? `$(pagination + '[rel="' + (t) + '"]', obj).parent().addClass('active')` doesn't work, because `pagination` is a jQuery object...

Comment: jquery is the first script called. Are you referring specifically to the fiddle?

Comment: @rvighne I tried your suggestion of adding defer to the script tag. There was no change to my page load document complete. The script I added the defer to showed up before document complete and not after like the script example I posted up on top.  I get what you are saying though...keep the script up in the head and just used the defer prevents the need from moving just before the closing body tag.

Comment: One interesting note is by putting defer in the script tag I am now getting an error on the $(function(){$('#loopedSlider1').loopedSlider1({autoStart:6000,restart:500,slidespeed:600,autoHeight:true});}); saying the $ in not defined

Comment: @KurtMarshman That wasn't an answer to your question, it was just a suggestion for after you got this problem solved.

Comment: @rvighne...either way I like and appreciate your suggestion.